# Bug. Why the panel locked when I'm creating a new mesh

Tags: mesh

[image]

Bug: when I type shift+A to add a new object such as a cube. I can't change any prosperty on the add-panel at the left down corner of screen.

I have noticed it several months ago, I have googled it, but looks like no one has the same issue as me.
and of cause it is uncommon. my software is alright before 2.81, but this issue happened when i upgraded to a lastest vesion serverl monthes ago I guess. and I found it maybe a bug can be sovled in the next version but apparently I was worng. I installed the lastest blender. still didn't work.

Comment: This is not a place to report bugs.

Comment: also: several months ago? Just try updating it again.